# Create link tag for webpack mini-css-extract-plugin extracted file without HTML

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I would like to package a javascript project with webpack 4 and I'm struggling with the CSS file.
My bundled JS file will be used by other website using a script tag with an absolute URI.
So I want my bundle to inject the link tag for the stylesheet in order to manage the hash in the filename.

My style source is a `scss` file.
It works well when I use the `style-loader` but I would like to extract the CSS in an other file.

I tried the following `webpack.config.js` :

```js
const miniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    miniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new miniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[hash].css',
        }),
    ]
};
```

It creates my CSS file in the output dir, but the loader doesn't inject it in the DOM like the `style-loader` does. And I can't use `style-loader` after the `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

I can't use `html-webpack-plugin` because there is no HTML output file.
Is there a way to do what I want with existing loaders ?
Is there a way to get the extracted file url in the JS to create the link tag by myself ?

My devDependencies :

```
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact I was in the wrong direction trying to use `mini-css-extract-plugin`. It can be achieved simply with this rule :

```js
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {
                injectType: 'linkTag'
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: "css/[name].[hash].css",
                publicPath: "dist/" // depends on your project architecture
            }
        },
        'sass-loader'
    ]
}
```

I will have to add another loader in order to minify I think.

Comment: Just to clarify why this works, the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` only runs the tag injection at build time whereas the `style-loader` adds the linkTag when running in the browser. If you you don't use the `HtmlWebPackTemplate` plugin or you do but with the inject set to false you need to use the style-loader plugin or manually write the css links in your html templates